# jsReport - Timeout error when passing data to child template

Tags: jsreport

We are using the jsReport HTML reporting engine.  We are using the cloud-based system at jsreportonline.net.

I am unable to get a child report to populate.

Please have a look to this link:-
https://playground.jsreport.net/studio/workspace/rkYn7WaCg/100

Subreports are an advertised feature of jsReport, but we are unable to get a child template to render.

Anyone have success with child templates?  Is there an error in how I am attempting to utilize this feature?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice when troubleshooting any kind problem in software development - **try to isolate it**.

Don't complain child templates timeout when you have a lot of other complexity around. Some scripts maps and other elements. Do you get the timeout when running html recipe? You would get much closer to the real problem and potentially solve it on your own before posting your question on the internet over and over. You just take our time to save yours.

Switching the phantom recipe to html shows no timeout. The timeout is likely caused because your custom printing trigger is not fired.

Your child template syntax is additionally not valid
`{#child childtemplate @data={{{toJSON this}}} }`

At this point you cannot pass handlebars context to the child template. You have only the option to pass custom parameter, like array index through `@data.paramA=val` additionally to the original data.

See the docs
https://jsreport.net/learn/child-templates